# Amazon Photo/Drive security documentation

Tags: cloud-computing, cloud-storage

I'm doing some research on Amazon drive/photo and I seem unable to find any security documentation on the subject. I'm aware that they are using AWS but I'm interested to learn more. Some people say that they are using Amazon S3. Has anybody read like a real document on what they are using to encrypt data, data transfer protocol etc?

Comment: This is a question for Amazon.

Comment: After googling, it is clear that data isn't encrypted. Traffic to clients is TLS.